# I am getting error with WordPress contact form 7

Tags: json, wordpress, forms

I am using contact form 7 version 4.9
When I try to submit the form, POST request is sent to this endpoint

`/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/<form id>/feedback`
But it gets `301 Moved Permanently` and GET request is sent to the endpoint `/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/<form id>/feedback` again.

As a result, I get this response `{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}` and form is not submitted.

Form is working on my local correctly but occurs error on server.
Anyone has ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution tested and working for me
Please downgraded to version 7.4.7 https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.4.7.zip it will work good

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and solved it when I noticed the WordPress install did not have a .htaccess file. I created a default .htaccess file and this fixed my contact form.